# How to output fields in an ArrayList to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea, settext

I'm trying to do something on the lines of:

```
    someJtextArea.setText(String.valueOf(
    for(int i = 1; i < 0; i++)
        {
            objInstance.anArrayList.get(i).getFirstName()
        }
    ));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append to the JTextArea:

Your for loop constraints by the way are a little *odd*.

For example:

```
for (Person person: objInstance.anArrayList) {
   someJTextArea.append(person.getFirstName() + "\n");
}
```

(Sorry about my previous wrong answer as I initially thought that you were adding to a JTextField)

Answer (score 2):

Build your String first and then set the text.

```
ArrayList<String> numList = new ArrayList<String>();
numList.add("One");
numList.add("Two");
numList.add("Three");

String text = "";

for (String num : numList) {
    text += String.format("%s%n", num);
}

myTextArea.setText(text);
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer is it because Strings are immutable so new Objects are being created in a loop? I guess it's inefficient but it won't make a difference in this example

Comment: Perfect practice makes perfect. While the example itself may not be an "issue", the issue is it demonstrartes bad practices